# how to use wget to input a string into a text box and hit "download" button

Tags: wget

I'm trying to batch query a website with wget. The box name contains spaces such as "Enter sequence here", and I need to click "Submit" button to search. Any ideas how to pass this to wget? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> The box name contains spaces such as "Enter sequence here", and I need
> to click "Submit" button to search. Any ideas how to pass this to wget?

`wget` is not *browser automation tool*, you would need other software if you want webbrowser to execute preprogrammed actions.

However, if above does send request to server and you are interesting in retrieving response to said request then `wget` might suffice. Please open developer tools (or similar - name might vary depending on browser) in your browsers (press F12 in Chrome) select network (or similar) then fill form and click `Submit`. Did new request appear? If so check its' verb, URL and headers, then construct suitable `wget` command based on this informaion.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion, I will try it! If not wget, would you suggest anything else, like curl?